# How do i automatically upload pictures from a folder onto canva using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an excel sheet that has a 100 numbers in a column, each of these numbers corresponds to the name given to a picture in a folder on the desktop. I need to upload these pictures from this folder onto the website canva in a way that each slide has one picture. the 100 slides are already made. i just need to upload each picture from the folder onto the slide according to the order in the excel sheet.
Any help would be appreciated.

havent tried anything yet as i dont know where to start

Comment: See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]